# How to set environment variable for my app service on Azure?

Tags: azure

I made a Web API service that I published on Azure. I want to be able to write to my blob storage from this service, so I need to add an environment variable for the storage connection string. In the Console (under Development Tools of the app service) I write the command:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot>setx AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING "<MyConnectionString>"
```

But I get the message:

> Error: Access to the registry path is denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the connection string in the portal by navigating to the **`Configuration`** section of the web app and add a new Key with named "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING" and the value

or set the connection string using the [`CLI command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/connection-string?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-connection-string-set),

```
az webapp config connection-string set --connection-string-type {ApiHub, Custom, DocDb, EventHub, MySql, NotificationHub, PostgreSQL, RedisCache, SQLAzure, SQLServer, ServiceBus}
                                       [--ids]
                                       [--name]
                                       [--resource-group]
                                       [--settings]
                                       [--slot]
                                       [--slot-settings]
                                       [--subscription]
```